# 14.04 wifi disconnect reason 2

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, disconnect

Ubuntu 14.04
HW: rt2860 (I'm sure since is my eeepc 1000he) BUT seen from ubuntu as rt2890

lspci:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe
```

module: rt28000pci

It's a wep connection, it connect just for a couple of minutes, then disconnect with reason 2, here just a few lines from dmesg.

```
[  238.999880] wlan0: authenticate with e0:91:53:25:0b:f1
[  239.012788] wlan0: send auth to e0:91:53:25:0b:f1 (try 1/3)
[  239.019096] wlan0: authenticated
[  239.019814] rt2800pci 0000:01:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  239.019836] rt2800pci 0000:01:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not         supported by the AP
[  239.019850] rt2800pci 0000:01:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  239.020176] wlan0: associate with e0:91:53:25:0b:f1 (try 1/3)
[  239.022206] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:91:53:25:0b:f1 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=17)
[  239.023239] wlan0: associated
[  239.023345] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  239.063810] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:91:53:25:0b:f1 (Reason: 2)
[  240.025701] wlan0: authenticate with e0:91:53:25:0b:f1
[  240.028223] wlan0: send auth to e0:91:53:25:0b:f1 (try 1/3)
[  240.032416] wlan0: authenticated
```

With open networks it works without problems, I'll check with WPA as soon as I can.
Any idea?

Comment: Reason 2 means Previous authentication no longer valid i.e., Client has associated but is not authorised

Comment: @Raphael, great, how can I see what's is going bad? With archlinux it worked, same essid, same wep key (and it's working right now with android)

Comment: Can you see the properties of your WEP wifi connection like is it WEP 128/40 bit OR 128bit?

Comment: Sure, on network-manager profiles is WEP 128/40 on the router is     Security : 128 bit WEP

Comment: Then delete all the existing wi-fi connections and create a new one from Network Connections.

Comment: Done, nm-applet says that I'm ok, but no way to reach the web and continue to deauth

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following commands one line at a time and just copy and paste for accuracy:

```
echo "options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci
```

This command changes encryption from hardware to software and in many cases corrects the issue you are having.

Wep is not very secure and ubuntu will connect to wpa2 (AES) (CCMP) better then any other settings,  not mixed mode or especially (TKIP).